# error in conversion of 2d array in C++ functions

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int x[2][2], int y[2][2],int z[2][2]);

int main()
{
   int a[2][2], b[2][2];
   cout << "Enter two matrices to add them " << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
       {
           cin >> a[i][j];
       }
   }
   cout << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
       {
           cin >> b[i][j];
       }
   }
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
     for(int j=0;j<2;j++)   
     {
        cout<<add(a[2][2],b[2][2])<<endl;
     }
   }

    return 0;
}

int add(int x[2][2], int y[2][2],int z[2][2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            z[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << z[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

I wanted to build a function that take values from user and add then and show them on console screen,
it can be done easily but i want to make a fuction. I have build one shown above but it does not executes
it shows me error that invalid conversion from int to int.

Comment: the arrays are called `a` and `b`, not `a[2][2]` and `b[2][2]`. Also `add` takes 3 parameters.

Comment: Unrelated: Make life easier and define the `add` function before you use it and skip the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout<<add(a[2][2],b[2][2])<<endl;
```

should be

```
cout<<add(a,b)<<endl;
```

This is a very common misunderstanding. To reference an array you use the name of the array (i.e. `a` or `b`) not the array and it's dimensions (i.e. `a[2][2]` or `b[2][2]`). You only need the dimensions of the array when you are declaring it, not when you are using it.

Plus (as fabian points out), you have written `add` with three parameters but you only call it with two. Perhaps you meant to make `z` local to `add` like this

```
int add(int x[2][2], int y[2][2])
{
    int z[2][2];
    ...
```

Now `add` has only two parameters.